# Why doesn't Elf64 use Elf64_Rel for relocations on 64-bit x86?

Tags: x86, x86-64, elf, relocation

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/819-0690/chapter6-54839.html#chapter7-2 states:

> 64–bit SPARC and 64–bit x86 use only Elf64_Rela relocation entries. Thus, the r_addend member serves as the relocation addend. x86 uses only Elf32_Rel relocation entries. The field to be relocated holds the addend.

There exists an `Elf64_Rel` struct, so why isn't it being used on 64-bit x86 targets? Doesn't using `Elf64_Rela` only waste space here as the pre-relocation addresses are just ignored (or at least are always 0 from what I've seen in testing)?

Note: `r_addend` is omitted in `Elf64_Rel`, not simply unused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> There exists an Elf64_Rel struct, so why isn't it being used on 64-bit x86 targets?

On `x86_64`, there are several possible [memory models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Memory_Model#x86-64). By default, the [small memory model](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/01/03/understanding-the-x64-code-models) is used, which doesn't need any 64-bit relocations.

If you compile with `-mcmodel=large`, then 64-bit relocations *will* be used.

Comment: Can you clarify how that explains why `mov eax, [rel foo + 12]` can't use the `rel32` in the machine code in the object file to hold the `+12`, instead using a relocation type that keeps that metadata separately?  Is it trying to handle a case like `mov eax, [rel foo + huge_offset]`, where the code is in range of the end of the array, but not of the `foo` symbol itself, so the rel32 field wouldn't be big enough?

Comment: @PeterCordes From what I can tell you're right about the why. Assembling `mov eax, [rel symbol + 0x1122334455667788]` gives `8b 05 00 00 00 00`, disassembled to `mov eax, dword [rip+0x0]` with a relocation entry of  `2: symbol+0x1122334455667784`, which clearly can't be put into the rel32. It does seem weird to me that the assembler doesn't do so when possible however. I feel like a bit of space could be saved by storing a list of Elf64_Rela's and a separate list of Elf64_Rel's.

Comment: @the4naves: Yeah.  It's very rare to ever link an executable (or library) where the symbol+offset is in range (for rel32 or abs32) but the symbol wouldn't be.  That would probably only happen with a linker script to put a large-data section before `.text`, and probably with hand-written asm that took advantage of the knowledge that `symbol+2G` would be in range even though `symbol` can't be assumed to be.  `gcc -mcmodel=medium` will just assume that any large arrays need to be referenced with 64-bit absolute addresses.